# Looking for Plugin that displays Facebook group's photos

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, facebook

There are several plugins that handle the auto retrieval/display of photos from my personal facebook profile, but i'm looking for one that will work w/ my facebook group. the group is way more active than the actual website and it'd be a bonus for the website to pull more content from FB.

have already looked at:
Facebook Photo Fetcher
Fotobook

neither would allow me to grant access to the group's photos even though i am an admin.  i'm sure there were a few more but it was a while back and i must have deleted them out of my plugins directory.

Comment: Could you list which one you already checked? Makes the task much easier :)

Comment: facebook photo fetcher and fotobook for sure.

Comment: Oh the shame! To be fair, I don't remember if this was off-topic 3 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look on [Embed Facebook](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/embed-facebook/). Just paste the URL of a facebook album, photo, event, video, page, group, or note in a WordPress post/page, the plugin will embed it for you.

For one more plugin is [Facebook Photos](http://tantannoodles.com/toolkit/facebook-photos/).:)